# RTP test tool - send RTP packets from a file

Tags: testing, rtp

I know this is a quite simple question which one could easily google and find. However, I have not been able to find a definitive tool that helps me with this. I have tried with rtpsend from rtptools also, but it gives me errors when run.

Hence pls suggest a tool that can read from a tcpdump/pcap file and send the RTP packets to the specified destination IP and port.

Thanks.

Comment: user@home:~/oRTP/rtptools-1.18$ ./rtpsend -v -f ~/rtp_example.raw 127.0.0.1/44444
Line ��� is invalid.
user@home:~/oRTP/rtptools-1.18$

Comment: @Mat, good to find an rtptools expert here. The error given by rtpsend is above. Please help me out.

Comment: @Mat, I have tried many sample rtp files both captured as well as samples from Internet. Can you provide a sample file?

Comment: The sample I used is from here - http://wiki.wireshark.org/H245

Answer (score 3):

I found a tool that can read from a file and stream the data to the destination IP address after encapsulating the data in RTP. The well known tool is VLC.

More info on how to use VLC for streaming is here - http://www.videolan.org/doc/streaming-howto/en/ch03.html